# Request to merge an unregistered profile

Tags: support, user-accounts

I posted an [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/266305/the-since-then-construction/267656#267656) by logging in as a guest. I want my guest login to be merged with this profile. When I try to contact the Help Center my request is invalidated as I don't have the other profile link to enter in the form. How can I get my profile merged with my guest login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the Help pages, which contain just what you need to know:

https://english.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: My problem was that I could not find the guest login's link. I anyways found it later.